# Find probability density function for $\varepsilon \cdot X$.

Tags: probability, density-function, exponential-distribution

Let $ X $ be exponentially distributed with parameter $\lambda > 0$ .

$a)$ Find the probability density function for $ Y := exp(X) $.

$b)$ Consider $X$ again. Now let $\varepsilon$ be  an independent random variable with $P(\varepsilon = 1 ) = \frac{1}{2}  $ and $P(\varepsilon = -1 ) = \frac{1}{2}  $. Find the probability density function for $\varepsilon \cdot X$.

So a) was no big deal. but I'm stucked in $b)$.

**Remark(Update)** : I read that $ \varepsilon  \cdot X $ has to be $Laplace(0,\frac{1}{\lambda})$ distributed.

We want to compute CDF of $YX$. [ $Y := \varepsilon$ ].
Let us say that $ a \ge 0 $

We start with $ F(a) = P(YX \le a) = P(X > -a | Y = -1)P( Y=-1) + P(X \le a |Y =1)P(Y=1) = P(X > -a)P( Y=-1) + P(X \le a)P(Y=1)  = \frac{1}{2} + (1-e^{-\lambda \cdot a}) \cdot \frac{1}{2}.   $

Then we take $F'(a)$ and get that $f(a)$ is $\frac{1}{2} \cdot \lambda \cdot e^{-\lambda \cdot a} $. So $YX$ is  $Lap(0,\frac{1}{\lambda})$.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Try to compute the CDF of $\varepsilon X$. Conditional on the value of $\varepsilon$ first and then split the range accordingly.

Comment: First of all: Thank you for your help. Do you mean we consider $ F(a) = P(\varepsilon \cdot X \le a) = \int_{-\infty}^{a} f_{\varepsilon \cdot X} (t) dt $? Sorry for the stupid question, but how can we compute  $\int_{-\infty}^{a} f_{\varepsilon \cdot X} (t) dt $ if we dont know what $f_{\varepsilon \cdot X} (t) dt $ is?

Comment: No, $P(YX \le a)=\sum_y P(X\le \frac{a}{y}|Y=y)P(Y=y)$, where my $Y$ is your $\varepsilon$. Then drop the condition in the conditional probability as $X$ and $Y$ are independent. Differentiate this cdf to obtain the density of $YX$. Note that the inequality in the 2nd step flips accordingly when $Y<0$.

Comment: @StubbornAtom. I see. I've tried this exercise again ( see above ). I even have the right solution. Nevertheless I think that I have some mistake. For example: I said that the sum you wrote is equal to $P(X > -a)P(Y=-1) + P(X \le a)P(Y=1) $. Is this right? I think I made a mistake.

Comment: Yes you wrote the sum correctly. But the simplification to find the density is not entirely okay. You should end up with the absolute value of $a$ in the pdf, where $a\in\mathbb R$.

Comment: You also need to calculate for $a < 0$, as mentioned above. The support of $\varepsilon X$ is the entire $\mathbb{R}$